# Can search for a record in a shapefile but how to get other fields

Tags: python, arcpy

I can search a shapefile for an attribute and it works fine but I don't know how to get the other fields in that record once the correct records is found. Don't know if I should use SearchCursor or SelectLayerByAttribute_management.

```
townlands = r'F:\MyProject\Assignment\townlands.shp'
outpath = r'F:\MyProject\Assignment'
the_townland=str(text_search_townland.get())
selection = str(""" "NAME_TAG" = '""" + the_townland + "'")
selection2 = ????????????????
print selection, selection2
```

This code is working in that it finds the townland that the user puts in text_search_townland and it prints it as selection. I'm looking to get another field called OSM_USER from that record into selection2.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working after lots of trial and error. It does need SearchCursor or at least that is how I got it working.

```
def new_record():

    #set environment variables.
    arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\MyProject\Assignment\folklore.gdb'
    myPath = r'F:\MyProject\Assignment\folklore.gdb'
    editRows = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('folklore', '*')
    print editRows.fields

    # get the centroid of the townland from townland_centroid (fc) based on the
    # townland the user enters.
    database = r'F:\MyProject\Assignment\folklore.gdb'
    fc = database + '/' + 'townland_centroid'

    the_townland=str(text_search_townland.get())
    fields = ['NAME_TAG', 'X_coord', 'Y_coord']
    whereClause = '"NAME_TAG"' + " = '" + the_townland + "'"

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, whereClause) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print('{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
    X_coord = str(row[1])
    Y_coord = str(row[2])
    del cursor

    # Set variables with values that will populate 'folklore' featureclass.
    OID = 1
    ptShape = arcpy.Point(0,0)
    townland = text_search_townland.get()
    county = var_county2.get()
    category = var_category.get()
    URL = text_search_URL.get()
    spec_location = "text_search_speclocation.get()"
    date_entered = text_search_date_entered.get()
    story_year = int(text_search_story_year.get())
    X_coord_put = X_coord
    Y_coord_put = Y_coord
    newRecord = [OID, ptShape, townland, county, URL, spec_location, date_entered, story_year, category, X_coord, Y_coord]
    editRows.insertRow(newRecord)
    del editRows
```

Hope this helps someone.